# AttributeError: module 'tensorrt' has no attribute 'infer'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorrt

I want use tensorRT to deploy my pytorch model.But I get a problem in import tensorRT.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fffan/fffan_files/Experiment/pytorch-tensorrt-master/model2trt.py", line 10, in <module>
      import calib as calibrator
  File "/home/fffan/fffan_files/Experiment/pytorch-tensorrt-master/calib.py", line 13, in <module>
      class PythonEntropyCalibrator(trt.infer.EntropyCalibrator):
  AttributeError: module 'tensorrt' has no attribute 'infer'
```

The code is like this:

```
    class PythonEntropyCalibrator(trt.infer.EntropyCalibrator):
        def __init__(self, input_layers, stream):
            trt.infer.EntropyCalibrator.__init__(self)
            self.input_layers = input_layers
            self.stream = stream

            self.d_input = cuda.mem_alloc(self.stream.calibration_data.nbytes)
            stream.reset()
```

**my tensorRT is 5.1.5.**
Somebody who knows please tell me.Thank you Very much!

Comment: Did you `import tensorrt.infer`?

Comment: Yes, I "import tensorrt as trt", and it tell me tensorrt has no infer.EntropyCalibrator  API.  The code is in tensorrt 4.  And now I use tensorrt 5.1.  Maybe the api is change.But I don't now this api in 5.1

Comment: `import tensorrt as trt` does not import `tensorrt.infer`.

Comment: I ```import tensorrt.infer```and get error like ```No module named 'tensorrt.infer```. How should I import in correct way?

Comment: It sounds like you might have shadowed the `tensorrt` package. If you named one of your own files `tensorrt.py`, pick a different name. (Check `tensorrt.__file__` to figure out where Python is resolving `tensorrt`.)

Comment: The code I use is here:  ```https://github.com/modricwang/Pytorch-Model-to-TensorRT```       And I really don't know because I have no files named ```tensorrt.py```. I just install it from Nvidia.